# How to get the total number of elements in a PCollection<String, String>

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

I want to get the total number of elements in a `PCollection<String, String>` in apache beam. I want to store this count for further use. How to write a java code for the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238203/how-to-count-elements-per-window ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count elements per window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238203/how-to-count-elements-per-window)

Comment: Hi @AnilMawji acarlstein thanks for the suggestion , I checked the solution but my scenario is different than what is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Apache Beam there is a transform called [Count](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Count.html) (The JavaDoc is the link here).  This has a method called `globally` which returns a PCollection containing the number of elements in the input PCollection.  You would use this method to get the count of elements.

Here is a fragment of logic that I used to test:

```
private class MyMap extends SimpleFunction < Long, Long > {
    public Long apply(Long in ) {
        System.out.println("Length is: " + in );
        return in;
    }
}

public void run(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create();
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    // Create a PCollection from static objects
    ArrayList < String > strs = new ArrayList < > ();
    strs.add("Neil");
    strs.add("John");
    strs.add("Bob");

    PCollection < String > pc1 = p.apply(Create.of(strs));
    PCollection < Long > count = pc1.apply(Count.globally());
    count.apply(MapElements.via(new MyMap()));

    System.out.println("About to run!");

    p.run().waitUntilFinish();

    System.out.println("Run complete!");
} // run
```

When run, this code creates a PCollection containing three strings.  I then apply the `Count.globally()` transformation and finally a Map to log the new PCollection which contains one element ... the length.

Comment: Hey thanks for info, actually i tried with that but wasnt successful. below is the code i tried.  PCollection composedProducts<String, String>;                                                                                                                     
   public static PCollection<Long> pi; pi = composedProducts.apply(Count.globally());

Comment: assume composedProducts has element. If i wish to get the count using pi PCollection. what is the code for the same? i want to get this count in a integer variable..how to do it?

Comment: Hey, one quick question, so if I need to access the length (in variable) in the MyMap class in the public void run(String[] args) method. How do I do that?

Comment: I believe that the high level answer is "you can't".  Here is my thinking.  In Apache Beam code, what you are actually doing is building a graph of activities that will "subsequently" be executed when you call the pipeline run method.  It is not correct to think about these statements as being executed when encountered ... rather think about p.run() as "sending" the whole graph (including the Java code for classes) to a remote server where it will be subsequently executed.

Comment: ok..so there is no way I guess to get this count from other methods....since a virtual vm is used to execute the graph. could you let me know if we can't get this count, in what scenarios this count.globally() would actually be used?

Comment: Apache Beam is used to process batch or streaming data.  Imagine if we had as input a stream of records where each record constitutes a product sale.  We might define a 24 hour window where at the end of the window we wish to emit a count of the number of sales during that day.  A branch in the pipeline might count (globally) all the daily sales and publish that as a Pub/Sub message or write it as a new row in a table.  Let me turn it around, what purpose are you thinking of using the count of elements in a PCollection for?

Comment: so my purpose was the same to get the count of records processed for a specific job. So my PCollection has all the elements processed in job, I was wondering if there is a way to get count of elements in the PCollection to log this count.

Comment: Remember that a pipeline doesn't have to be one single linear chain.  It can have splits in it.  I am imagining a sequence of transformations that perform processing work on your input and then culminate in an output from that PCollection.  There is nothing to prevent you from creating a split and in parallel to the output of the primary PCollection, generate another PCollection that contains just the one count element and then output that in addition to your primary pipeline path.

Comment: I tried the same thing, the code is-->    PCollection composedProducts<String, String>; public static PCollection<Long> pi; pi = composedProducts.apply(Count.globally());   i am not sure if this is the correct way of creating a single value PCollection to solve my problem. Any thoughts?